# an algorithm for checking if a string is mirrored string in objective-c language

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, comparison

This is regarding the depth of string functions in objective.
What are the best string methods that I can use in writing a method that tells a string variable is a mirrored string or not. The method should take NSString as argument, and give out a boolean value as the result of whether the string is mirrored or not.

Comment: I couldn't get at the individual characters to compare them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

BOOL isPalindrome(NSString *string) {
    int length = [string length];
    for(int i=0; i<length/2; i++){
        if ([string characterAtIndex:i] != [string characterAtIndex:(length - 1 - i)]){
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *word = @"ABCDEDCBA";
        NSLog(@"%@? %@", word, isPalindrome(word) ? @"Y":@"N");
    }
}
```